# exclude the first <tr> tag - Xpath

Tags: xpath

`

```
<table border="1px" cellpadding="10px" style="background-color:rgb(247, 247, 247); border-collapse:collapse; border:1px; height:450px; max-width:650px; width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255); border-color:rgb(236, 238, 239); height:50px; width:628px">
        <span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>Descrizione tecnica</strong></span></span></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color:rgb(244, 249, 252); border-color:rgb(236, 238, 239); height:50px; width:304px">
        <span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif"><strong>CPU Dissipatore</strong></span></span></span>
      </td>
      <td style="background-color:rgb(244, 249, 252); border-color:rgb(236, 238, 239); height:50px; width:303px">
        <span style="color:#000000"><span style="font-size:14px"><span style="font-family:trebuchet ms,helvetica,sans-serif">Intel i7-11700K<p></p>
                    Dissipatore a Liquido 240mm
          </span></span>
  </span>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

`

I have to extract all the contents of the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags

except the first `<tr>` tag

Xpath code: /table/tbody/tr/td

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you want to use a positional predicate of `/table/tbody/tr[position() > 1]/td`.